# Delete previous fields in firebase except personal data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

there is a problem I am trying to solve but I can not find a solution to it.
I wrote code in nodejs, for the app I am building in React, I save the information in firebase.

Each time I add fields with a different name, which is why there are fields I can not delete. I want every time before I put new fields, to delete the previous fields - but there are some fields that I owe and I must not delete them like: handle ,email, website, location and an image.

[image]

I thought of doing delete on the fields, but it erases everything for me - and does not leave me the fields I want.
This is what I wrote down so far, here I am adding new fields that the user has selected, but I also want to delete some of the old fields, but I can not use delete because it deletes everything for me.

code:

```
exports.addUserPreferences = (req, res) => {
  let userPreferences = reduceUserPreferences(req.body);
 
  db.doc(`/preferences/${req.user.handle}`)
    .update(userPreferences)
    .then(() => { 
      return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};
```

I want to delete all the fields except the ones I need, I'm not sure how to do that.

***add more info***

userPreferences is an object - that has fields that I add to firebase for example:

```
{
  "sport_tennis": "5",
  "sport_running": "4",
  "sport_swimming": "5",
  "study_history": "0"
}
```

These were the fields I last added to firebase.

But as you can see there will be fields that I want to delete, for example in the picture there are fields that I do not want like: tennis.

userPreferences - This is an object that returns different preferences that the user has, whenever preferences can be different - previous preferences should be deleted and not saved

Comment: Please edit the question to show what `userPreferences` contains, the existing contents of the document, and be clear about what this code is doing with that data that's different than what you expect.  What you have right now is difficult to understand.

Comment: thank you for helping, basiclly, userPreferences is an object - that has fields that I add to firebase.

Comment: You can use `FieldValue.delete()` to mark specific fields for deletion at the time of an update.  Use the documentation as a guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields

Comment: Thanks for the help, I do not think I understood your intention. There may be a lot of fields I need to delete, I know which fields I should not delete.

Comment: Firestore doesn't know either.  You have to tell it.  If you want to overwrite everything completely, don't use `update()` - use `set()` instead.

Comment: thank you for help, i will try you set instead, i will hope that is will work.